# Increase disk storage

Tags: dual-boot, windows, storage

I can not shrink the `boot drive` i.e. `C` anymore, in order to reuse that space for the ubuntu partition which I have installed on dual boot.

I want to know how to shrink the `F` partition and merge that space into my ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can just boot with a Ubuntu live CD (or USB), and resize everything with gparted.